# Как получить доступ к результату работы потоков над общим ресурсом

Tags: java, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Программа решает следующую задачу: есть несколько файлов с текстом, на каждый файл через пул потоков создается поток для открытия и чтения файла и составление из прочитанного текста списка из строк `List<String>`, далее предполагается использование общего для всех потоков `Map<String, Long>` для сбора статистики следующим образом - ключом(key) будет соответственно строка из списка, а значение(value) равно 1, но если такой ключ уже присутствует т.е. в списке и в других списках имеются одинаковые строки, то инкрементировать значение на единицу

Если первый файл содержит строки "Hello", второй соответственно две строки "Java" и "World", а третий файл "Hello", то результирующий map должен выглядеть так:

```
{"Hello"=2,"Java"=1, "World"=1}
```

**Моя реализация:** Все работает корректно

В методе makeStatistics()создается экземпляр класса (Statistic), где находится общий map, далее метод makeStatistics() с помощью метода getFilesPaths() вычисляет пути к файлам с расширением .txt и заносит из в список, далее создает фиксированный пул потоков размером, равным количеству текстовых файлов в папке(1 файл - 1 поток), потом в цикле создаются экземпляры классов для потока ReaderThread, в его конструктор передается экземпляр класса (Statistic) с общим map-ом и путь к файлу

```
public ArrayList<Path> getFilesPaths() {
    ArrayList<Path> filesNames = null;
    try (Stream<Path> files = Files.walk(Paths.get("D:\\DIR"))) {
        filesNames= files
                    .filter(file -> file.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        filesNames.forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return filesNames;
}

public void makeStatistics() {

    Statistic statistic = new Statistic();

    ArrayList<Path> logPaths = getFilesPaths();
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(logPaths.size());

    for (Path filePath : logPaths)
    {
        ReaderThread logReader = new ReaderThread(statistic, filePath);
        executor.execute(logReader);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Класс потока выглядит так, он просто читает файл, по переданному в него пути и сохраняет строчки в список, потом в строке statistic.setStatisticMap(textLines); список отправляется на изменение общего map-а в классе Statistic

```
public class ReaderThread implements Runnable {

private Path filePath;
private Statistic statistic;

public ReaderThread(Statistic statistic, Path filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
    this.statistic = statistic;
}

public Path getFile() {
    return filePath;
}

public void run() {   
        List<String> textLines;
        try(Stream<String> lineStream = Files.newBufferedReader(filePath).lines()) {
            textLines = lineStream
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

            statistic.setStatisticMap(textLines);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

А вот и класс с общим map-ом:

```
public class Statistic {

private Map<String, Long> statisticMap;

public Statistic() {
    statisticMap = new HashMap<>();
}

public synchronized void setStatisticMap(List<String> logLines) {
    statisticMap = logLines.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 1L, Long::sum));

    System.out.println(statisticMap);
}

public Map<String, Long> getStatisticMap() {
    return statisticMap;
}
```

Программа выводит на экран правильный результат, но меня интересует как и в каком месте получить доступ к уже построенному общему map-у(statisticMap), т.е. как и где получить доступ к statisticMap после того как его сформируют потоки и он будет заполнен?

Comment: ну у вас есть метод getStatisticMap, который возвращает мапу. не пойму в чем проблема

Comment: @Senior Pomidor , если в методе `makeStatistics()` после `executor.shutdown();`
написать `System.out.println(statistic.getMinuteStatisticMap());` выведется {} пустой map и выведется он перед началом работы потоков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
executor.shutdown();
```

Не будет дожидаться выполнения всех переданных задач. Самый простой способ, воспользоваться методом invokeAll и немного переделать реализацию.

```
public class ReaderThread implements Callable<Object> {

    private Path filePath;
    private Statistic statistic;

    public ReaderThread(Statistic statistic, Path filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.statistic = statistic;
    }

    public Path getFile() {
        return filePath;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        List<String> textLines;
        try (Stream<String> lineStream = Files.newBufferedReader(filePath).lines()) {
            textLines = lineStream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

            statistic.setStatisticMap(textLines);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

И вызывать его через executor так:

```
    List<ReaderThread> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Path filePath : logPaths) {
        tasks.add(new ReaderThread(statistic, filePath));
    }
    try {
        executor.invokeAll(tasks);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
    System.out.println(statistic.getStatisticMap());
```